# Python unittest : setUpClass uses a non-static method

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm quite a beginner in Python and started designing a unit test in Python and i need to post some messages to the server before i run the test class (cause it's gonna search for them). Thus i need to call a non-static method `postMessages()`.

the stack-trace of the error i'm getting is this-

```
    Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../TestMsgs.py", line 23, in setUpClass
    instance = cls()
  File ".../python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'TestMsgs.TestMsgs'>: runTest
```

i have something like this in the code:

```
class A(object):

    def postMessages(self):
        print "i post messages in the server!"

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.foo()  # should post messages for the tests in the class to work on
```

There's no option, right now, to make foo static. How can i instantiate B (or A, for that matter) in postMessages() so i can use it in setUpClass() ?

Comment: Please post your code for your test cases. It looks like you might be making "test cases" as classes without inheriting unittest.TestCase. Then the test runner is trying to invoke runTest from your classes and of course doesn't find it. Or the reverse. You are misusing the TestCase class as one of your own classes. Anyway, please post some content directly from your unit test file.

Comment: Is `foo` a class method on `B` that calls `postMessage`? It's not clear from the code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having a read through the `__init__` method for TestCase I see that you need to provide a test method name to it. The default is "runTest" which is why that error was popping up.

```
import unittest 

class A(unittest.TestCase):

    def postMessages(self):
        print "i post messages in the server!"

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.foo(cls(methodName='test_method')) # should post messages for the tests in the class to work on

    def foo(self):
        self.postMessages()

    def test_method(self):
        pass


B.setUpClass()
```

You can see it running in an [interactive Python console here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/gists/5237014/gistfile1.txt/ipython2/?affiliate_id=000003f6). It will print out "i post messages in the server!"

The reason you need to pass in a valid method name in the class can be clearly seen in the [source code for unittest](http://pythonhosted.org/gchecky/unittest-pysrc.html):

```
class TestCase: 
    """A class whose instances are single test cases.""" 

    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'): 
        """Create an instance of the class that will use the named test 
           method when executed. Raises a ValueError if the instance does 
           not have a method with the specified name. 
        """ 
        try: 
           self._testMethodName = methodName 
           testMethod = getattr(self, methodName) 
           self._testMethodDoc = testMethod.__doc__ 
           except AttributeError: 
               raise ValueError, "no such test method in %s: %s" % \ 
                   (self.__class__, methodName)
```

If you want to pass in parameters to the method that you have just passed in then you would need to do something like

```
class A(unittest.TestCase):

    def foo(self, arg1):
        pass

a = A(methodName='foo')
a.foo('an_argument')
```

But this whole question just feels really wrong. You should refactor rather than have a static method calling an instance method. It's just silly.

Comment: you got what i want to do pretty well. unfortunately refactoring is not much of an option at this point so i'll have to work around it. I've tried what you suggested already and the error i get is: ValueError: no such test method in <class 'Abc. Abc'>: runTest.

Comment: I can't tell from your question what the problem might be now. Why don't you post the full stracktrace? And any relevant code.

Comment: Ah! Now I see the error when the `A` class actually inherits from unittest.TestCase... give me a minute.

Comment: can you is this some sort of hack or is this how you're supposed to do it? could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: It is not a hack, `unittest.TestCase` must be initialised with one of it's own method names. It defaults to `runTest`. Normally when you are forming a collection of tests to run then the test runner does just that. It's only because you are doing something quite weird (calling an instance method from a classmethod) that you are forced to do this manually.

Comment: but then shouldn't the method name point to 'foo' (that does the functionality that i want) instead of 'test_method' that does nothing?

Comment: Well, it's never going to get run unless you also pass the test instance to a test runner...  If you really want to understand how a TestCase class works you should just read the documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) or the code. A TestSuite is a collection of TestCase instances that have been initialised with different method names.

Comment: and what if i need to pass parameters to such a method? how would i go about that?

Comment: edited the answer, I would reccomend reading the source code that I linked to. It's quite clear and simple to understand and will answer all your questions.

Comment: yeah i already did... forgot to remove the comment. thanks either way :) most appreciated